# WSO2 API Manager : Extracting and sending client identity to the backend host

Tags: wso2-api-manager

So we have

- API published in **WSO2 API management**
- This is consumed by two consumers, A and B.

SETUP --

- **Consumers(A or B)**   ----*OAuth + data* ---> **WSO2_APIM(Authorization done)** ---> **Backend host**

Now we need to send the consumers identity to backend host.

For Ex -
**Consumer B** ----*OAuth + data* ----> **WSO2_APIM(Authorization done)** ---*Header(client='B')*---> **Backend host**

Please suggest, cite how can we achieve this?

TIA

Comment: Have you checked [Passing End User Attributes to the Backend](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-via-api-gateway/) ?

Comment: do you want to send end username to backend as a header? The question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.

1. Use a custom sequence and add a header

- You can extract some data that is coming in the request and based on
  that you can add a header
  https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/message-mediation/passing-a-custom-authorization-token-to-the-backend/#passing-a-custom-authorization-token-to-the-backend

2. Enable backend JWT

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/choreo-connect/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-via-choreo-connect/#passing-end-user-attributes-to-the-backend